# Rational homotopy type of a complement

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, rational-homotopy-theory

Let $X$ and $X'$ be smooth closed manifolds. Take closed subpolyhedra $D\subset X$ and $D'\subset X'$ (with respect to some triangulations) and let $f:X\to X'$ be a homotopy equivalence such that $f(D)=D'$ and the restriction of $f$ to $D$ is also a homotopy equivalence. Is it possible for the complements $X-D$ and $X'-D'$ to have different rational homotopy types, assuming all spaces ($X,X',D,D'X-D,X'-D'$) simply-connected?

Here is some motivation behind the question: if we replace the rational homotopy type with the integral one and do not require the spaces to be simply connected, then the answer is yes, as shown in a paper by R. Longoni and P. Salvatore http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401075; a much simpler example is in Ryan's comment below. On the other hand, additively the cohomology of $X-D$ and $X'-D'$ is obviously the same.

upd: in the first version of the question the simple connectedness condition was missing. Apologies for the mix-up.

Comment: There is a homotopy equivalence $(S^3,K_1) \to (S^3,K_2)$ with $K_1$ the unknot, and $K_2$ the trefoil.   


Comment: Thanks, indeed! What if we assume everything simply connected?

Comment: I think Salvatore ?might? have a result analogous to his paper with Longoni using simply-connected manifolds instead of lens spaces. The argument proceeds much the same -- the configuration spaces aren't homotopy-equivalent even though the underlying manifolds are. I'll ask him about it in person next week. I'll visit Longoni as well.  I don't think Salvatore has written up that paper yet.  Longoni is a banker in Milano. 

Comment: @Ryan - +1 for the "Longoni is a banker in Milano" statement!

Comment: There's no knot examples to your revised question. Smale proved that even inequivalent smooth knots in $S^n$ (with codimension $>2$) have diffeomorphic complements. 

Comment: If everything is simply connected, then it seems like Mayer-Vietoris and the 5-lemma shows $f$ induces an isomorphism on rational homology, and hence by Hurewicz/Whitehead it's a rational homotopy equivalence. I figured this was really a $\pi_1$ question.   

Comment: @Paul: The map f does not necessarily induce a map between the complements.

Comment: Longoni's response to your question is "hasn't anything happened in mathematics in the past 10 years?" (joking)  Salvatore says he'll eventually log into MathOverFlow and give a proper response.

Comment: Woops, it seems that quite a lot happened in this thread since I last looked at it (and probably in mathematics in the past years as well:)). Ryan, thanks, I'd be interested in hearing Salvatore's response. In the mean time, what exactly is the statement? Is it that the rational homotopy type of the configuration spaces is not determined by the rational homotopy type of the manifold? Or the same statement with "rational" replaced by "integral"? Or a mixture of both?

Comment: I think he has an example of homotopy-equivalent simply-connected manifolds that are not homeomorphic such that certain configuration spaces in the manifolds are not homotopy-equivalent.   I don't know if he's using rational homotopy techniques or not but I think it's likely. 

Answer (score 2):

Some of the best results known along these lines are in the paper

- Pascal Lambrechts, Don Stanley, *Algebraic models of Poincaré embeddings*, Algebr. Geom. Topol. **5** (2005) 135-182, doi:[10.2140/agt.2005.5.135](https://doi.org/10.2140/agt.2005.5.135), arXiv:[math/0503605](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503605),

which used to be called "Algebraic models of complements...".
Briefly, it seems that even if the complement is simply connected, there are examples of what you seek when the codimension is too small, and when the codimension is large enough the rational homotopy type of a complement is determined.

Comment: Thanks, Dev! I am aware of that paper, but I do not know whether in the examples given in section 9 there one can construct a homotopy equivalence of couples.